# Network not connecting after "power event" at datacenter

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, cisco

This is a very weird issue, so I will give as much detail as possible.

Our datacenter had a "Power Event" (e.g. PDU failure), and after which several bad things happened. First and foremost, our Cisco SG200-50 switch lost its configuration and reverted to factory defaults, and while 4 of our 5 servers did come back up and operate normally afterward, one server could not connect to either our public or private networks. Both NICs on that server showed "Unidentified Network", and while they did keep the assigned IPs (both static), no connectivity was present.

After restoring our switch config, same deal with that one server. No connectivity whatsoever. After trying everything we could think of to restore connectivity, we eventually got it so that it would ping our local network, but would not use the gateway on that nic and had no internet access, and the network still identified as "Unidentified Network"

It was determined that the NIC must have been damaged, and so it was replaced with a new NIC. Same result. The new NIC would not connect to the network with the same exact result.

We then connected that server with one of our other servers via a crossover cable, which worked fine on the NIC that would not allow network access. Since that server is a Hyper-V host, we simply copied the VPSs off of it to another host, started them up, then completely wiped that host (even destroying the RAID and re-creating it), and re-installed Windows (2012 R2 Datacenter edition). After all that... same exact result. Neither the original nor new NIC (and +1 replacement after the reinstall as well) will connect to either network. WE also replaced the CAT cables and used different switch ports, all to no avail.

My only guess at this point is that the motherboard has a issue.. it is a older server (Dell poweredge 2950), but nothing to indicate a problem is showing up - all drivers loading, no weird devices in device manager, etc.  The NICs we have tried are from different manufacturers, and we tried both CAT5 and CAT 6 cabling. The only thing we have not yet tried is plugging in directly to the datacenters router, but I do have that in process - it takes a while because we have a special Routed Port drop from the datacenter and I guess its a right pain in the ass for them to set up another one of those. But I seriously doubt that will fix it as the other servers on the same switch connect just fine with no issues whatsoever.

Anyway.. I am hoping one of the experts here have seen something like this before and can shed some light on it. Any info is greatly appreciated!

Comment: New nic means PCI express lan card?

Comment: Yes... Network Interface Card. We have tried 3 total, 1 of the 2 new ones was identical to the original, the other was a different manufacturer.

Comment: You have done almost all the troubleshooting steps. As you mentioned in your post check your motherboard.

Comment: That's the thing... besides just replacing it, I am not sure how or if it can be further checked. Its showing no obvious errors... Is there a way I do not know about to actually check it, like software or something? Dell had nothing like that that I saw. I was hoping I was missing something. I am not a network tech, but a general "IT Guy" type. Not really an expert in this :/

Comment: Is this Hyper-V host joined to an AD domain? My assumption is yes. What is it using for DNS? How many virtual switches are configured in Hyper-V? Which virtual switches are shared with the management OS?

Comment: It was yes. It was using the primary DC for DNS. About 3-4 hours in to debugging I ended up removing all 3 virtual switches, to make network debugging easier. And I moved to google DNS. Now its a fresh windows install not attached to the domain, since I can't even get LAN to work in order to attach it. We have multiple networks, 1 public (non-AD), 1 AD and 1 non-AD private. None of them will even ping.

Comment: Oh, and the current install does not even have Hyper-V installed, so the virtual switches are not a issue at this time.